# Python: How to print a word one letter at a time

Tags: python

How do I use Python to print a word one letter at a time? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Need a lot more info here.  Where are the words coming from?  What determines how long the delay between prints is?  One letter at a time or one word at a time (pick one)?

Comment: So, one word at the time, or a word one letter at the time?

Answer (score 2):

If i understood you correctly than you can use the following code:

```
for word in text.split():
    print word
```

else if you need to print word's letters:

```
for let in word:
    print let
```

In case you need to skip punctuation and so on you can also use regEx:

```
tst = 'word1, word2 word3;'

from re import findall

print findall(r'\w+', tst)
```

Or not very pythonic:

```
skipC = [':','.', ',', ';']# add any if needed

text= 'word1, word2. word3;'

for x in skipC:
    text = text.replace(x, ' ')

for word in text.split():
    print word
```